# C# language specification "Program Instantiation" appears to be mis-identified

Tags: c#, language-specifications

In the C# language specification a Program is defined as

> **Program** the input to the compiler.

While an Application is defined as

> **Application** an assembly that has an entry point

But, they define

> **Program instantiation** — the execution of an application.

Given the definition of "Program", shouldn't this be...

> **Application instantiation** — the execution of an application.

instead?

Comment: Could you give spec references for all these? There may be notes in the annotated version, but I can't find "Program instantiation" in the C# 4 spec (at least in the hard copy)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Sure thing http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at the wrong specs.

Comment: Brian: Ah, the ECMA specs. They're slightly different. Will try to find my annotated ECMA version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this term doesn't occur in the Microsoft version of the specification. The annotated ECMA spec has this annotation after "Program":

> **Programs, assemblies, applications and class libraries**
>   This definition of program differs from common usage. In C#, a program is just the *input* to the compiler. The *output* of the compiler is an *assembly*, which is either an *application* or a *class library*.

There aren't any other annotations nearby though. It does seem somewhat odd, which is perhaps why it doesn't appear in the MS spec.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you have a link to the current MS version you can share?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: I keep a list of links at http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Specifications.aspx

Answer (score 3):

No.

They're definitions, so they can be whatever they want.  Your mistake is attempting to find a semantic link in the word `program`, where there is none.  They are, as you've noted, unrelated.

What they're saying is "this is how we use this term"; there's basically nothing wrong with choosing any term, as long as the *definitions* are consistent. `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` would have been just as correct as `program instantiation`.  As long as the names are internally consistent, and the *definitions* are correct, the names could be anything.  They're just labels.

Someone at Microsoft obviously thought that it was more important that the term `program instantiation` be reflected in it's common usage.  The term `program` probably didn't get the same treatment but, again, they're just names.  And the names are "atomic": the word `program` is not at all related to the term `program instantiation`.

---

Since they're just labels, they terms can be replaced by anything.  One possibility is:

> `X` = the input to the compiler.
>
> `Y` = an assembly that has an entry point
>
> `Z` = the execution of `Y`.

Replacing any of the names with anything else makes no difference in their usage.

If I replace the above definition of `Z` with a new term `XY`:

> `XY` = the execution of `Y`

this still holds.  It's just a label, it gets semantic content from the definition, not from it's name.  `XY` has no semantic relationship to `X`, and it's relationship to `Y` is only incidental.

---

When you read definitions of things, especially technical specifications, it's important to keep this in mind.  There's often no best term for something, as there are often multiple common terms for the same thing, and they're not often defined rigourously enough to be meaningful in a precise specification.

There's an [entire branch of philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language) dedicated to issues like this, and causing a "conflict" in the sense that you cite is pretty much unavoidable.

The writer's of the C# specification made their choice, and as long as it's internally consistent, it's "correct".

Answer (score 1):

Based on given input, what the compiler outputs is still the program, only in the format of an assembly / application, such that it is:

> **Program, valid** — a C# program constructed according to the syntax rules and diagnosable semantic rule.

I'll take a brave step here and say that we could remove ourselves from such specific context and look at an available definition of [usage in English for `Program`](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/program):

> 1. (6) A set of coded instructions that enables a machine, especially a
>      computer, to perform a desired
>      sequence of operations.
> 2. (7) An instruction sequence in programmed instruction.

Both what is input to the compiler and that which is output can both be labelled by the above.

But actually, I'm going to have to vote to close as this is a question regarding the semantics of the English language.

Comment: I thought about posting on http://english.stackexchange.com/, but this question is specific to programmers and also has a specific answer regarding an important language so I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: I know, it's nagging me a little as I think the same. I've flagged it for mod attention along with giving my thoughts, so let's see what they make of the predicament.